# Rearrange 2D grid

Tags: clustering, combinatorics

I have a 2D grid on which I represent data points:

[image]

Here, the red data point activates the grid on positions (1,1), (1,4) and (2,3). The blue data point activates the grid on positions (1,1), (4,3), (2,4). The green data point activates the grid on positions (1,2), (1,3) and (2,4).

Each activated cell has a specific meaning. The positions of the cells is total random. The green data point is uncorrelated with red, although it is lying between two red points. The blue and red data point are somehow correlated since they share one activation.

What I want is to rearrange the cells so that co-occuring cells are closer to each other:

[image]

Here, cell (1,1) moved to (2,3). The other two red activations are above, the other to two blue activations are below. The cells of the green activation moved closer to the edge since they share no cells with the other two data points.

My idea was to do some kind of greedy permutation: Given a number of datapoints, their activation and a few possible permutations, I could calculate the most promising permutation. The problem is that I have a 64x64 grid with 300k data points...

Does anyone have a good strategy on how to permute the cells?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  First, the sense of "uncorrelated" is not evident.  Second, *of course* you can re-arrange the cells any way you want. If there's a problem with that, it must be because there are constraints on or costs to the possible rearrangements: it's essential that you explain that.